# Adding a NLP model in the MS bot creating an issue on Azure?

Tags: azure, nlp, botframework, chatbot

So, I am working on a project to build an AI Chatbot using the MS bot framework. In a particular situation, I am capturing the user messages and sending them to an NLP model to classify their intents. To be more specific, I am using the waterfall context here.

So, the user message is step_context.result, then I am sending this message to a model to classify and return its corresponding class.

The issue is that It is working fine in localhost, but when I deploy the bot on Azure, It is not replying at those places where I use the NLP model externally. Though it is working and answering perfectly where I have not used or called any NLP model.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am also adding ss for reference.

[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0HtF.png)
[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TQgp.png)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, you are not getting proper response when the code moved to azure and using NLP. Kindly provide the error message or the screenshot of the output working in localhost to identify the proper solution for the problem.

Comment: When I am running the code on the local host, the bot is giving me the response properly where I have used NLP to classify sentences,. But when I am deploying it to the azure, it is not responding where I have used NLP to classify those messages and respond according to the result. But it is working where I haven't used any NLP to classify messages.

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot 2 (python code), torch is the library which was not installed properly and as the requirements are not clear in the question, providing the flow of steps to be followed to attach NLP to the azure chat bot with the working procedure.

The below is the [URL](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/13.core-bot) for the code block.

Comment: The torch library is perfectly installed. In the picture, I have just opened the code for taking screenshots. You are not getting my point, I have built an NLP model using python. So, when I am taking the message from the user, I just pass this to my NLP model for classify its intents.  I am not using LUIS here.